# Vaadin cuts off (not scrollable) when screen size changed

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin layout that works fine on a larger screen. As soon as the screen size (and the resolution) drop, all the contents get cut off and no scrollbar appears.

I tried using a Panel to remedy the issue, but the panel likewise gets cut off.

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
panel.setContent(horizontalSplit);
panel.setSizeFull();
panel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();
```

I also tried using

```
Responsive.makeResponsive(horizontalSplit)
```

but it still cuts off

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want scrollbars or layout to be resized after window size change? Please post any screen too.

Answer (score 0):

If you set

```
panel.setSizeFull();
```

and

```
panel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();
```

then it is normally to content be cutt of on small screens.

Solution is to setSizeFull() on panel content too.

Comment: actually I debugged the setup yesterday - the issue was that the VerticalLayout which contained all the components wasn't "setSizeFull", so the components would cut off.
I set the layout to setSizeFull and got the scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style in your **styles.scss** file

```
.overflow-auto{
        overflow : auto;
      }
```

Then set StyleName to your panel

```
panel.setStyleName("overflow-auto");
```